# c language if statement with sizeof

Tags: c, if-statement, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   if (sizeof(int) > -1)
       printf("True");
   else
       printf("False");
}
```

ANSWER:

> False

but according to the logic `sizeof(int)` return 2 and `if(2>-1)` return 1 and it should print True.

Why it is behaving otherwise?

Comment: This would likely have been caught if you had more warnings enabled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, the value produced by `sizeof` is of `size_t` which is `unsigned` type. <sup>NOTE</sup>

As the `unsigned` type is of higher *rank* than the `signed` type, while performing the comparison, as per the norms of the relation operator,  the usual arithmetic conversions are performed, meaning the signed type is promoted to unsigned type.

In your case, the `-1`, when considered as `unsigned`, represent the highest possible `unsigned` value, thus, no wonder

```
 if (sizeof(int) > -1)
```

Evaluates to *false*.

Moral of the story: Attempted comparison between a `signed` and an `unsigned` is *expected* to produce weird result, just as in your case. You should enable compiler warning and try to solve the issues reported by the compiler.

---

NOTE:

From `C11`, chapter §7.19, `<stddef.h>`,

> `size_t`
>   which is the `unsigned` integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is an operator which returns the size and the returned value type is `unsigned int`.
Since `unsigned` is having higher rank than `singed` type, -1 is treated as unsigned number.
-1 in this case is treated as 0xFFFF. 
Hence `if (sizeof(int) > 0XFFFF)` is evaluated to `false`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
if ( ( int )sizeof(int) > -1)
```

you will get the expected result that is `True`.

Operator sizeof returns a value of type `size_t` that corresponds to some implementation defined unsigned integer type.

From the C STandard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 5 The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined,
>   **and its type (an unsigned integer type)** is size_t, defined in  (and other headers).

The rank of `size_t` in any case greater than or at least equal to the rank of type `int`. It means that when the compiler need to determine the type of an expression it converts operand will lower rank to the type of the operand with higher rank. If operands have the same rank but one operand has unsigned integer type and other has signed integer type then the common type is unsigned int type.

Thus in the condition of the if statement

```
if ( sizeof(int) > -1)
```

`-1` is converted to unsigned integer type `size_t` and due to its internal representation where all bits are set to 1 is freater than the value of `sizeof( int )`

Comment: Actually, because of the way the standard specifies conversions from signed to unsigned, the internal representation of a negative number doesn't really matter...  `-1` converts to the same unsigned value regardless (maximum value for the unsigned type).